# Analyzing multiply imupted data from Amelia in R: Why do results from zelig and mice differ?

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, mice

Motivated by my answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69130/how-to-get-pooled-p-values-on-tests-done-in-multiple-imputed-datasets), I played around with analyzing mulitply imputed data from the `Amelia` package in R. As I have explained in my answer, the multiply imputed datasets can be analyzed using the combined `Zelig` and `mitools` packages or using a combination of `Zelig` and `mice`.

Now, to me it seemed rather inconvenient to fit the linear model using `zelig()` as `mice`, too, provides the `with.mids()`-function to fit linear models to multiply imputed datasets. However, I found that the results differ depending on the function used for fitting. For the analysis using `with.mids`, I first had to circumvent a bug in the current `mice`-package by defining the following function, as has been explained in [another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71908/14646):

```
as.mids2 <- function(data2, .imp=1, .id=2){
  ini <- mice(data2[data2[, .imp] == 0, -c(.imp, .id)], maxit=0)
  names  <- names(ini$imp)
  if (!is.null(.id)){
    rownames(ini$data) <- data2[data2[, .imp] == 0, .id]
  }
  for (i in 1:length(names)){
    for(m in 1:(max(as.numeric(data2[, .imp])) - 1)){
      if(!is.null(ini$imp[[i]])){
        indic <- data2[, .imp] == m & is.na(data2[data2[, .imp]==0, names[i]])
        ini$imp[[names[i]]][m] <- data2[indic, names[i]]
      }
    }
  }
  return(ini)
}
```

Once I had done this, I used `Zelig`:

```
library("Amelia")
data(freetrade)
amelia.out <- amelia(freetrade, m = 15, ts = "year", cs = "country")

library("Zelig")
zelig.fit <- zelig(tariff ~ pop + gdp.pc + year + polity, data = amelia.out$imputations, model = "ls", cite = FALSE)
zelig.results <- lapply(zelig.fit, function(x) x$result)

library("mice")
zelig4mice <- as.mira(zelig.results)
zelig.mice.res <- summary(pool(zelig4mice, method = "rubin1987"))
```

Then I tried the same thing using only `mice`:

```
imp.data <- do.call("rbind", amelia.out$imputations)
imp.data <- rbind(freetrade, imp.data)
imp.data$.imp <- as.numeric(rep(c(0:15), each = nrow(freetrade)))
mice.data <- as.mids2(imp.data, .imp = ncol(imp.data), .id = NULL)

mice.fit <- with(mice.data, lm(tariff ~ polity + pop + gdp.pc + year))
mice.res <- summary(pool(mice.res2, method = "rubin1987"))
```

These are the results:

```
> zelig.mice.res
                  est       se     t    df Pr(>|t|)     lo 95     hi 95 nmis   fmi lambda
(Intercept)  3.18e+03 7.22e+02  4.41  45.9 6.20e-05  1.73e+03  4.63e+03   NA 0.571  0.552
pop          3.13e-08 5.59e-09  5.59 392.1 4.21e-08  2.03e-08  4.23e-08   NA 0.193  0.189
gdp.pc      -2.11e-03 5.53e-04 -3.81 329.4 1.64e-04 -3.20e-03 -1.02e-03   NA 0.211  0.206
year        -1.58e+00 3.63e-01 -4.37  45.9 7.11e-05 -2.31e+00 -8.54e-01   NA 0.570  0.552
polity       5.52e-01 3.16e-01  1.75  90.8 8.41e-02 -7.58e-02  1.18e+00   NA 0.406  0.393

> mice.res
                  est       se     t     df Pr(>|t|)     lo 95     hi 95 nmis    fmi lambda
(Intercept)  3.42e+03 8.87e+02  3.86   8.01 4.80e-03  1.38e+03  5.47e+03   NA 0.7599 0.7066
pop          3.20e-08 5.25e-09  6.10 504.30 2.10e-09  2.17e-08  4.24e-08    0 0.0927 0.0891
gdp.pc      -2.09e-03 5.31e-04 -3.93 189.23 1.19e-04 -3.13e-03 -1.04e-03    0 0.1543 0.1454
year        -1.70e+00 4.46e-01 -3.83   8.02 5.02e-03 -2.73e+00 -6.78e-01    0 0.7594 0.7061
polity       5.74e-01 3.60e-01  1.59  13.93 1.34e-01 -2.00e-01  1.35e+00    2 0.5907 0.5358
```

From these data it is apparent, that the linear models fit by the two methods differ and so do the determined degrees of freedom.

**Why do these results differ? What is the correct analysis procedure?**

Comment: It seems that as.mids2() does not produce a proper mids-object. It returns 5 imputations instead of 15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stef is right. An initial mice object is created in `as.mids2()` with `m = 5` as a default. Even though the `mids` object is completely filled in, the `with()` function only uses the first five. This is because the number of imputations - corresponding to the largest value in `.imp` - is not changed in the returned object. The following code yields the correct `mids` object

```
as.mids2 <- function(data2, .imp=1, .id=2){
  ini <- mice(data2[data2[, .imp] == 0, -c(.imp, .id)], m = max(as.numeric(data2[, .imp])), maxit=0)
  names  <- names(ini$imp)
  if (!is.null(.id)){
    rownames(ini$data) <- data2[data2[, .imp] == 0, .id]
  }
  for (i in 1:length(names)){
    for(m in 1:(max(as.numeric(data2[, .imp])))){
      if(!is.null(ini$imp[[i]])){
        indic <- data2[, .imp] == m & is.na(data2[data2[, .imp]==0, names[i]])
        ini$imp[[names[i]]][m] <- data2[indic, names[i]]
      }
    } 
  }
  return(ini)
}
```

and yields the same results as `Zelig` given the active random seed.

```
> zelig.mice.res
                      est           se         t        df     Pr(>|t|)         lo 95
(Intercept)  3.118344e+03 7.031673e+02  4.434711  55.20608 4.437533e-05  1.709283e+03
pop          3.074658e-08 5.993667e-09  5.129844 211.31179 6.550041e-07  1.893154e-08
gdp.pc      -2.185839e-03 5.968324e-04 -3.662400 174.91116 3.308584e-04 -3.363759e-03
year        -1.551702e+00 3.535625e-01 -4.388762  55.26609 5.183456e-05 -2.260180e+00
polity       4.649357e-01 3.102389e-01  1.498638 125.11682 1.364865e-01 -1.490600e-01
                    hi 95 nmis       fmi    lambda
(Intercept)  4.527404e+03   NA 0.5206397 0.5035824
pop          4.256162e-08   NA 0.2643263 0.2573962
gdp.pc      -1.007919e-03   NA 0.2909757 0.2829145
year        -8.432231e-01   NA 0.5203580 0.5033089
polity       1.078931e+00   NA 0.3448966 0.3345077

> mice.res
                      est           se         t        df     Pr(>|t|)         lo 95
(Intercept)  3.118344e+03 7.031673e+02  4.434711  55.20608 4.437533e-05  1.709283e+03
pop          3.074658e-08 5.993667e-09  5.129844 211.31179 6.550041e-07  1.893154e-08
gdp.pc      -2.185839e-03 5.968324e-04 -3.662400 174.91116 3.308584e-04 -3.363759e-03
year        -1.551702e+00 3.535625e-01 -4.388762  55.26609 5.183456e-05 -2.260180e+00
polity       4.649357e-01 3.102389e-01  1.498638 125.11682 1.364865e-01 -1.490600e-01
                    hi 95 nmis       fmi    lambda
(Intercept)  4.527404e+03   NA 0.5206397 0.5035824
pop          4.256162e-08    0 0.2643263 0.2573962
gdp.pc      -1.007919e-03    0 0.2909757 0.2829145
year        -8.432231e-01    0 0.5203580 0.5033089
polity       1.078931e+00    2 0.3448966 0.3345077
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Gerko! I was trying to figure this out yesterday, but was unable to fix it. Now, this should probably be migrated to StackOverflow.